# Access Denied - Unable to authenticate login - spring security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I work on simple authentication app using spring security & encounter by an access denied error. I must mention that registration works perfectly & I've already created 1 record with bcrypted password but on login I'm failed to understand that what did I miss. Grateful for the help

User.java

```
public class User implements UserDetails {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;
private String name;
private String username;
private String email;
private String password;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JsonIgnore
private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    Set<GrantedAuthority>authorities = new HashSet<>();
    userRoles.forEach(ur -> authorities.add(new 
   Authority(ur.getRole().getName())));
    return authorities;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}
}
```

SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private UserSecurityService userSecurityService;

public SecurityConfig(UserSecurityService userSecurityService) {
    this.userSecurityService = userSecurityService;
}

@Bean
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}



@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws 
Exception {
auth.userDetailsService(userSecurityService).passwordEncoder
(passwordEncoder());
}

@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws 
 Exception {return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
}
```

UserSecurityService (loaduser)

```
@Service
public class UserSecurityService implements UserDetailsService {
private static final Logger LOG = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserSecurityService.class);

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;


@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws 
   UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findUserByUsername(username);
    if (null == user) {
        LOG.warn("Username {} not found", username);
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username " + username + " 
  not found");
    }
    return user;
}
```

}

AuthController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthController {

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
private RoleRepository roleRepository;

@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Autowired
private UserService userService;


@PostMapping("/register")
public ResponseEntity<User> register(@RequestBody User user) throws Exception {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(userService.register(user), HttpStatus.OK);
}

@PostMapping("/login")
public ResponseEntity<String> login(@RequestBody String username, String password ) throws 
  Exception {
    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new 
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
        username, password
    ));
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    return new ResponseEntity<>("User signed -in succesfully", HttpStatus.OK);
 }
 }
```

Error

```
2022-01-14 14:49:13.604  INFO 24600 --- [  restartedMain] 
c.kash.bankingAPI.BankingApiApplication  : Starting 
BankingApiApplication using Java 11.0.12 on LAPTOP-BQ48GM36 with PID 
24600 (B:\spring\bankingAPI\target\classes started by The Kash in 
B:\spring\bankingAPI)
2022-01-14 14:49:13.605  INFO 24600 --- [  restartedMain] 
c.kash.bankingAPI.BankingApiApplication  : No active profile set, 
falling back to default profiles: default
2022-01-14 14:49:13.673  INFO 24600 --- [  restartedMain] 
.e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults 
 active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
 2022-01-14 14:49:13.674  INFO 24600 --- [  restartedMain] 
.e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related 
logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2022-01-14 14:49:14.557  INFO 24600 --- [  restartedMain] 
.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data 
JPA 
repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-01-14 14:49:14.646  INFO 24600 --- [  restartedMain] 
.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data 
repository scanning in 74 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-01-14 14:49:15.876  INFO 24600 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with 
port(s): 8088 (http)
2022-01-14 14:49:15.890  INFO 24600 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-01-14 14:49:15.890  INFO 24600 --- [  restartedMain] 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: 
[Apache Tomcat/9.0.56]
 2022-01-14 14:49:16.008  INFO 24600 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C. 
[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded 
WebApplicationContext
2022-01-14 14:49:16.008  INFO 24600 --- [  restartedMain] 
w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root 
WebApplicationContext: 
initialization completed in 2334 ms
2022-01-14 14:49:16.264  INFO 24600 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing 
PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-01-14 14:49:16.332  INFO 24600 --- [  restartedMain] 
org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM 
 core 
version 5.6.3.Final
 2022-01-14 14:49:16.542  INFO 24600 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate 
Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-01-14 14:49:16.661  INFO 24600 --- [  restartedMain] 
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-01-14 14:49:17.128  INFO 24600 --- [  restartedMain] 
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start 
completed.
2022-01-14 14:49:17.145  INFO 24600 --- [  restartedMain] 
org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: 
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
2022-01-14 14:49:18.469  INFO 24600 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using 
JtaPlatform implementation: 

[org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.
NoJtaPlatform]
2022-01-14 14:49:18.478  INFO 24600 --- [  restartedMain] 
j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA 
EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-01-14 14:49:19.173  WARN 24600 --- [  restartedMain] 
JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is 
enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed 
during 
view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to 
disable 
this warning
2022-01-14 14:49:19.453 DEBUG 24600 --- [  restartedMain] 
edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control 
expression [permitAll] for Ant [pattern='/api/**', GET]
2022-01-14 14:49:19.455 DEBUG 24600 --- [  restartedMain] 
edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control 
expression [permitAll] for Ant [pattern='/api/auth/**']
2022-01-14 14:49:19.456 DEBUG 24600 --- [  restartedMain] 
edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Adding web access control 
expression [authenticated] for any request
2022-01-14 14:49:19.468  INFO 24600 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request 
with 
[org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.
WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@4b607819, 
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistence
Filter@146dcdcf, 
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@74f0174b, 
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.
LogoutFilter@839ff7f, 
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.
BasicAuthenticationFilter@4f78b9a2, 
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.
RequestCacheAwareFilter@7e2b3eef, 
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolder
AwareRequestFilter@1996d59a, 
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Anonymous
AuthenticationFilter@d82cd0b, 
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagement
Filter@47842f0b, 
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslation
Filter@6fdc8d32, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.
FilterSecurityInterceptor@3619bc38]
2022-01-14 14:49:19.922  INFO 24600 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is 
running 
on port 35729
2022-01-14 14:49:19.959  INFO 24600 --- [  restartedMain] 
o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 
8088 (http) with context path ''
2022-01-14 14:49:19.970  INFO 24600 --- [  restartedMain] 
c.kash.bankingAPI.BankingApiApplication  : Started 
BankingApiApplication 
in 6.835 seconds (JVM running for 7.645)
2022-01-14 14:49:51.914  INFO 24600 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C. 
[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring 
DispatcherServlet 
'dispatcherServlet'
2022-01-14 14:49:51.915  INFO 24600 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 
'dispatcherServlet'
2022-01-14 14:49:51.916  INFO 24600 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
 o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization 
in 
1 ms
2022-01-14 14:49:51.931 DEBUG 24600 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /api/auth/login
2022-01-14 14:49:51.936 DEBUG 24600 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder 
to 
empty SecurityContext
2022-01-14 14:49:51.939 DEBUG 24600 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder 
to 
anonymous SecurityContext
2022-01-14 14:49:51.940 DEBUG 24600 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
o.s.s.w.session.SessionManagementFilter  : Request requested invalid 
session id 1E5E812360CC1B8291311CA85ACAC55A
2022-01-14 14:49:51.945 DEBUG 24600 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorized filter 
invocation 
[POST /api/auth/login] with attributes [permitAll]
2022-01-14 14:49:51.946 DEBUG 24600 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST 
/api/auth/login
 Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_7_, user0_.email as email2_7_, 
user0_.name as name3_7_, user0_.password as password4_7_, 
user0_.primary_account_id as primary_6_7_, user0_.savings_account_id 
as 
savings_7_7_, user0_.username as username5_7_ from users user0_ where 
user0_.username=?
2022-01-14 14:49:52.305  WARN 24600 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
c.k.b.s.serviceImpl.UserSecurityService  : Username {
"username": "seeshee",
"password": "12345"
} not found
2022-01-14 14:49:52.313 DEBUG 24600 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Failed to find user '{
"username": "seeshee",
"password": "1234"
}'
2022-01-14 14:49:52.698  WARN 24600 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
o.a.c.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase        : Creation of SecureRandom 
instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [364] 
milliseconds.
2022-01-14 14:49:52.700 DEBUG 24600 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
 o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request 
http://localhost:8088/api/auth/login to session
2022-01-14 14:49:52.701 DEBUG 24600 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
 s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using 
Reque 
 tHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expec 
 edHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
2022-1-14 14:49:52.701 DEBUG 24600 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
  s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : No match found. Using 
 default entry point 
 org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.
 BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@691634d7
 2022-01-14 14:49:52.702 DEBUG 24600 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
 w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty 
SecurityContext
2022-01-14 14:49:52.702 DEBUG 24600 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store empty 
SecurityContext
2022-01-14 14:49:52.702 DEBUG 24600 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared 
SecurityContextHolder 
to complete request
2022-01-14 14:49:52.705 DEBUG 24600 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /error
2022-01-14 14:49:52.705 DEBUG 24600 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder 
to 
 empty SecurityContext
2022-01-14 14:49:52.706 DEBUG 24600 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder 
to 
 anonymous SecurityContext
 2022-01-14 14:49:52.706 DEBUG 24600 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
 o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /error
 2022-01-14 14:49:52.721 DEBUG 24600 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
a.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator : filter invocation [/error] 
denied for AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, 
Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, 
Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 
SessionId=BAFE9322A4A2705325C4B6540915129E], Granted Authorities= 
[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is 
denied
    at 
org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased. 
decide(AffirmativeBased.java:73) 
~[spring-security-core-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.
DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.isAllowed
(DefaultWe 
 bInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.java:100) ~[spring-security-web- 
5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.
DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.isAllowed
(DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.java:67) ~[spring-security- 
web- 
5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
at 
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.ErrorPageSecurityFilter.
isAllowed
 (ErrorPageSecurityFilter.java:84) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
at 
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.ErrorPageSecurityFilter.
doFilter
(ErrorPageSecurityFilter.java:72) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
at 
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.ErrorPageSecurityFilter.
doFilter
(ErrorPageSecurityFilter.java:66) ~[spring-boot-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(
ApplicationFilterChain.
java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~ 
[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
at 
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.
doFilter
(FilterChainProxy.jav 
a:327) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.
FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke
(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:106) ~[spring-security-web- 
5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.
FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter
(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web- 
5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$
VirtualFilterChain.doFilter
(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.
 ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter
(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-web- 
 5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
at 
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.
doFilter
       (ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web- 
5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$ 
 VirtualFilterChain.doFilter
  (FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
 at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter
.doFilter
(SessionManagementFilter.java:87) ~[spring-security-web- 
5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.
 doFilter
(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web- 
5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
at 
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
.doFilter
(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.
AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter
(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-security-web- 
5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$
VirtualFilterChain.doFilter
(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.
SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.
doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring- 
security-web- 
 5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$
VirtualFilterChain.doFilter
(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.
RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter
(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web- 
5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$
VirtualFilterChain.doFilter
 (FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter
 (OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$
VirtualFilterChain.doFilter
  (FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.
LogoutFilter.doFilter
  (LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.
LogoutFilter.doFilter

(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
at 
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.
doFilter

(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(
 OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) 
  ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilter
 Chain.doFilter
 (FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
at 
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistence
Filter.doFilter
  
 (SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web- 
 5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
at 
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistence
 Filter.doFilter
   (SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web- 
  5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
at 
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.
 doFilter
   (FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter
    (OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at 
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.
doFilter
  (FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal
   (FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter
   (FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
at 
 org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate
  (DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter
 (DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~ 
  [spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
 (ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core- 
 9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
  (ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core- 
 9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
at 
 org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal
   (RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter
  (OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
   (ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core- 
  9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
  (ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core- 
 9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter
    (OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
   (ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core- 
  9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
 (ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core- 
 9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter
    (OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
   (ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core- 
 9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter
   
  (ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core- 
 9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke 
   (ApplicationDispatcher.java:711) ~[tomcat-embed-core- 
 9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest
 (ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) ~[tomcat-embed-core- 
 9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward
   (ApplicationDispatcher.java:385) ~[tomcat-embed-core- 
 9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward
    (ApplicationDispatcher.java:313) ~[tomcat-embed-core- 
 9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom
   (StandardHostValve.java:403) ~[tomcat-embed-core- 
 9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status
 (StandardHostValve.java:249) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
 [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
at 
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run
(TaskThread.java:61) ~ 
[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2022-01-14 00:49:13.289 DEBUG 21332 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store anonymous 
SecurityContext
2022-01-14 00:49:13.289 DEBUG 21332 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store anonymous 
SecurityContext
2022-01-14 00:49:13.289 DEBUG 21332 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] 
s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared 
 SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

Comment: first of all, you are have enabled basicLogin, which i dont really understand why since you are not using basic login, so that should be removed. You should be using `formLogin` instead, and set the `loginPage` to your login endpoint `/login` if you insist on writing a custom login endpoint. Otherwise you can just remove your custom endpoint, enable `formLogin` and then sen spring security will provide a default login implementation on `/login` that takes in `username` and `password`as `form parameters`

Comment: i recommend you start out by trying to get `formLogin` working without a custom login point, before trying to do custom things.

Comment: I update an error log now start with beginning. Sorry I don't understand why should I use formlogin() ? as this is an API authentication not via HTML form. The problem is that  loaduser doesn't getting username. If you have any solution ? tks

Comment: FormLogin has nothing to do with you make a login form, or that you need a login form. FormLogin means that you take in FORM parameters and not JSON parameters. Most commonly people use a form to send FORM parameters, but you can use postman, curl or whatever to send FORM parameters. I suggest you learn how to set up FORM login, before trying to write a fully customised login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logs say this:

```
2022-01-14 14:49:52.305  WARN 24600 --- [nio-8088-exec-2] c.k.b.s.serviceImpl.UserSecurityService  : 
Username { "username": "seeshee", "password": "12345" } not found
```

If we look in your code we can see the following line:

```
login(@RequestBody String username, String password )
```

This is your faulty code line, as it doesn't do what you think it does. You think it will take the json and extract the two parameters `username` and `password` and set these. But what it actually does is that the `@RequestBody` will take the entire body (the json) and set it to the parameter that is defined on, which is `username`.

So what spring is doing is that it will extract the entire json body and place it into the `username` string.

Then you try to use that to login, and then you get the error message posted above.

What you need to do is to create a holder class that spring can deserialize into.

```
public class RequestBody {

    public RequestBody(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    // getters, setters

}

@PostMapping("/login")
public ResponseEntity<String> login(@RequestBody RequestBody requestBody ) throws Exception {
    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new 
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
        requestBody.getUsername(), requestBody.getPassword()
    ));
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    return new ResponseEntity<>("User signed -in succesfully", HttpStatus.OK);
 }
```

You can read about how to use requestbody here:

[Spring’s RequestBody and ResponseBody Annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-response-body)

Comment: Thats correct ! I'd have to created another class with login properties. Since I did the same all work well.                                                                        

    public ResponseEntity<String> login(@RequestBody Login login) throws Exception {
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            login.getUsername(), login.getPassword()